# How to Add values/columns from two MySQL queries in a single MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

I have the following two queries which work great alone, but I need to combine them into a single query to get the "Jan Totals", "Feb Totals", "Mar Totals", etc.

Calculation for Jan would be: (Jan + Jan_webl) AS Jan_Total, but not sure how to reference the two values/columns in order to SUM them?

The first query output is:

```
"Average"   "Jan"   "Feb"   "Mar"   "Apr"   "May"   "Jun"   "Jul"   "Aug"   "Sep"   "Oct"   "Nov"   "Dec"   "Total"
"97086.8276"    "42550" "33200" "42950" "30192" "48216" "58650" "41451" "16320" ""  ""  ""  ""  "2815518"
```

The second query output is:

```
"weekly_Avg"    "Jan_webl"  "Feb_webl"  "Mar_webl"  "Apr_webl"  "May_webl"  "Jun_webl"  "Jul_webl"  "Aug_webl"  "Sep_webl"  "Oct_webl"  "Nov_webl"  "Dec_webl"  "Total_webl"
"53270.0000"    "0" "0" "0" "50"    "19925" "35025" "48975" "27000" "0" "0" "0" "0" "130950"
```

### Query #1

```
SELECT 
AVG(febl_remaining) as 'Average',
MAX(CASE febl_month WHEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%01') THEN febl_remaining END) 'Jan',
MAX(CASE febl_month WHEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%02') THEN febl_remaining END) 'Feb',
MAX(CASE febl_month WHEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%03') THEN febl_remaining END) 'Mar',
MAX(CASE febl_month WHEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%04') THEN febl_remaining END) 'Apr',
MAX(CASE febl_month WHEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%05') THEN febl_remaining END) 'May',
MAX(CASE febl_month WHEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%06') THEN febl_remaining END) 'Jun',
MAX(CASE febl_month WHEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%07') THEN febl_remaining END) 'Jul',
MAX(CASE febl_month WHEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%08') THEN febl_remaining END) 'Aug',
MAX(CASE febl_month WHEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%09') THEN febl_remaining END) 'Sep',
MAX(CASE febl_month WHEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%10') THEN febl_remaining END) 'Oct',
MAX(CASE febl_month WHEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%11') THEN febl_remaining END) 'Nov',
MAX(CASE febl_month WHEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%12') THEN febl_remaining END) 'Dec',
SUM(febl_remaining) as 'Total'

FROM
(   SELECT 
    1 as id, 
    DATE_FORMAT(tblcom.omActCompDate, '%Y-%m') AS febl_Month,   
    IF 
    (   SUM(DISTINCT weEstBuildLgth) IS NULL, 
          SUM(DISTINCT tblcom.omEstBuildLgth), 
          SUM(DISTINCT tblcom.omEstBuildLgth) - SUM(DISTINCT weEstBuildLgth)
    ) AS febl_remaining
FROM      tblweeklyebl 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN tblcom ON tblweeklyebl.comID = tblcom.omID 
WHERE tblcom.omstatusID Like 'Closed'
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(tblcom.omActCompDate, '%Y-%m')
) t 
GROUP BY t.id
```

### Query #2

```
SELECT 
SUM(DISTINCT tblcom.omEstBuildLgth - tblweeklyebl.weEstBuildLgth) / COUNT(DISTINCT   

IF(tblcom.omEstBuildLgth - tblweeklyebl.weEstBuildLgth = 0, NULL,  
MONTH(tblweeklyebl.weDate))) AS weekly_Average,

   SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblweeklyebl.weDate, '%Y-%m') =   
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%01') THEN (tblweeklyebl.weEstBuildLgth) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Jan_webl',
   SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblweeklyebl.weDate, '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%02') THEN (tblweeklyebl.weEstBuildLgth) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Feb_webl',
   SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblweeklyebl.weDate, '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%03') THEN (tblweeklyebl.weEstBuildLgth) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Mar_webl',
   SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblweeklyebl.weDate, '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%04') THEN (tblweeklyebl.weEstBuildLgth) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Apr_webl',
   SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblweeklyebl.weDate, '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%05') THEN (tblweeklyebl.weEstBuildLgth) ELSE 0 END) AS 'May_webl',
   SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblweeklyebl.weDate, '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%06') THEN (tblweeklyebl.weEstBuildLgth) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Jun_webl',
   SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblweeklyebl.weDate, '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%07') THEN (tblweeklyebl.weEstBuildLgth) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Jul_webl',
   SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblweeklyebl.weDate, '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%08') THEN (tblweeklyebl.weEstBuildLgth) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Aug_webl',
   SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblweeklyebl.weDate, '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%09') THEN (tblweeklyebl.weEstBuildLgth) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Sep_webl',
   SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblweeklyebl.weDate, '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%10') THEN (tblweeklyebl.weEstBuildLgth) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Oct_webl',
   SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblweeklyebl.weDate, '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%11') THEN (tblweeklyebl.weEstBuildLgth) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Nov_webl',
   SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblweeklyebl.weDate, '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%12') THEN (tblweeklyebl.weEstBuildLgth) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Dec_webl',
   SUM(DISTINCT tblweeklyebl.weEstBuildLgth) AS Total_webl    

FROM      tblweeklyebl RIGHT OUTER JOIN tblcom ON tblweeklyebl.comID = tblcom.omID
```

Optionally: How do you list the data vertically such as:

```
tebl month
44550 Jan
33200 Feb
48450 Mar
34942 Apr
53516 May
62700 Jun
46651 Jul
78690 Aug
```

Something like: GROUP BY Month ORDER BY MONTH(tblcom.omActCompDate) ?

Comment: What data do you expect from each query?  Just one row by the looks of things?  If so you can have each query as a subquery which you treat as a table in the out query.  if you have multiple rows you need to work out an id you can use as a join condition to match the right rows together

Comment: Is there a field in both queries that you could use to join them together? Might not be the best solution when it comes to performance but just join both queries by wrapping them both in a subquery. When that works... have a look at performance.

Comment: @jiig can you post a sql fiddle with some data and the schema? i can then test my answer with your data :)

Comment: John, see my updated post above.. never done a sqlfiddle.. I added in the data samples, and wondered how to list the data vertically if needed? ps: your query worked great, just had one typo.. change second comma to a period (t2.weekly_average).

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will work.. but I need data to test it

```
SELECT 
    t1.Average, t2,weekly_average, 
    t1.Jan + t2.Jan_webl AS Jan_Total, 
    t1.Feb + t2.Feb_webl AS Feb_Total,
    t1.Mar + t2.Mar_webl AS Mar_Total,
    t1.Apr + t2.Apr_webl AS Apr_Total,
    t1.May + t2.May_webl AS May_Total,
    t1.Jun + t2.Jun_webl AS Jun_Total,
    t1.Jul + t2.Jul_webl AS Jul_Total,
    t1.Aug + t2.Aug_webl AS Aug_Total,
    t1.Sep + t2.Sep_webl AS Sep_Total,
    t1.Oct + t2.Oct_webl AS Oct_Total,
    t1.Nov + t2.Nov_webl AS Nov_Total,
    t1.Dec + t2.Dec_webl AS Dec_Total,
    t1.Total, t2.total_webl
FROM
(   SELECT 
        AVG(febl_remaining) as 'Average',
        MAX(CASE febl_month WHEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%01') THEN febl_remaining END) 'Jan',
        MAX(CASE febl_month WHEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%02') THEN febl_remaining END) 'Feb',
        MAX(CASE febl_month WHEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%03') THEN febl_remaining END) 'Mar',
        MAX(CASE febl_month WHEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%04') THEN febl_remaining END) 'Apr',
        MAX(CASE febl_month WHEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%05') THEN febl_remaining END) 'May',
        MAX(CASE febl_month WHEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%06') THEN febl_remaining END) 'Jun',
        MAX(CASE febl_month WHEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%07') THEN febl_remaining END) 'Jul',
        MAX(CASE febl_month WHEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%08') THEN febl_remaining END) 'Aug',
        MAX(CASE febl_month WHEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%09') THEN febl_remaining END) 'Sep',
        MAX(CASE febl_month WHEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%10') THEN febl_remaining END) 'Oct',
        MAX(CASE febl_month WHEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%11') THEN febl_remaining END) 'Nov',
        MAX(CASE febl_month WHEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%12') THEN febl_remaining END) 'Dec',
        SUM(febl_remaining) as 'Total'
    FROM
    (   SELECT 
            1 as id, 
            DATE_FORMAT(tblcom.omActCompDate, '%Y-%m') AS febl_Month,   
            IF 
            (   SUM(DISTINCT weEstBuildLgth) IS NULL, 
                SUM(DISTINCT tblcom.omEstBuildLgth), 
                SUM(DISTINCT tblcom.omEstBuildLgth) - SUM(DISTINCT weEstBuildLgth)
            ) AS febl_remaining
        FROM tblweeklyebl 
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN tblcom ON tblweeklyebl.comID = tblcom.omID 
        WHERE tblcom.omstatusID Like 'Closed'
        GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(tblcom.omActCompDate, '%Y-%m')
    ) t 
    GROUP BY t.id
) t1
JOIN
(   SELECT 
        SUM(DISTINCT tblcom.omEstBuildLgth - tblweeklyebl.weEstBuildLgth) / 
        COUNT(DISTINCT   
            IF(tblcom.omEstBuildLgth - tblweeklyebl.weEstBuildLgth = 0, NULL, MONTH(tblweeklyebl.weDate))
        ) AS weekly_Average,
        SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblweeklyebl.weDate, '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%01') THEN (tblweeklyebl.weEstBuildLgth) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Jan_webl',
        SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblweeklyebl.weDate, '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%02') THEN (tblweeklyebl.weEstBuildLgth) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Feb_webl',
        SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblweeklyebl.weDate, '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%03') THEN (tblweeklyebl.weEstBuildLgth) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Mar_webl',
        SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblweeklyebl.weDate, '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%04') THEN (tblweeklyebl.weEstBuildLgth) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Apr_webl',
        SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblweeklyebl.weDate, '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%05') THEN (tblweeklyebl.weEstBuildLgth) ELSE 0 END) AS 'May_webl',
        SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblweeklyebl.weDate, '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%06') THEN (tblweeklyebl.weEstBuildLgth) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Jun_webl',
        SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblweeklyebl.weDate, '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%07') THEN (tblweeklyebl.weEstBuildLgth) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Jul_webl',
        SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblweeklyebl.weDate, '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%08') THEN (tblweeklyebl.weEstBuildLgth) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Aug_webl',
        SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblweeklyebl.weDate, '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%09') THEN (tblweeklyebl.weEstBuildLgth) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Sep_webl',
        SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblweeklyebl.weDate, '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%10') THEN (tblweeklyebl.weEstBuildLgth) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Oct_webl',
        SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblweeklyebl.weDate, '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%11') THEN (tblweeklyebl.weEstBuildLgth) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Nov_webl',
        SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblweeklyebl.weDate, '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%12') THEN (tblweeklyebl.weEstBuildLgth) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Dec_webl',
        SUM(DISTINCT tblweeklyebl.weEstBuildLgth) AS Total_webl    
    FROM tblweeklyebl 
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN tblcom ON tblweeklyebl.comID = tblcom.omID
) t2
```

btw I'm glad to see you took my first query and expanded it! you're learning!!